# Realmで取得したデータをUICollectionViewで表示

Tags: swift, realm, uicollectionview

現在Realmを使って画像データとテキストを保存し、UICollectionViewで画像のみの表示を行っています。
UICollectionViewのセルをクリックすると画面遷移を行い、保存した画像とテキストを表示させたいと考えています。
イメージとしては、通販サイトなどで商品をクリックし、その詳細ページに飛ぶ感じです。

データの保存とUICollectionViewで画像の表示まではできたのですが、その後画像（セル）をクリックしてデータをどのように遷移先に送るのかがわかりません。
普通の変数などであればSegueで値を渡せると思うのですが、
データベースの場合も表示されている値を格納した変数をSegueで送ることは可能なのでしょうか？

```
//メンバ変数
  var a : ToDo?

  var toDoItems:Results<ToDo>?{
    do{
        let realm = try Realm()
        return realm.objects(ToDo)
    }catch{
        print("エラー")
    }
    return nil
   }
...
 extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return toDoItems?.count ?? 0
}
    //データを返すメソッド
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{

    let toDo = toDoItems?[indexPath.row]
    let cell =      collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! collectionviewcell
cell.image1.image = toDo?.image
return cell
    }
    // Cell が選択された場合
      func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        var toDo = toDoItems?[indexPath.row]
        a = toDo
        if a != nil{
            performSegueWithIdentifier("toSubViewController",sender: nil)       
        }

    }

    // Segue 準備
    func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        if (segue.identifier == "toSubViewController1") {
            let subVC: SubViewController = (segue.destinationViewController as? SubViewController)!
            subVC.a1 = a
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 基本的な手順としては、セルを選択したタイミングでインデックスが取れるので、Realmからそのインデックスに対応するデータを取り出し、次の画面に渡します。コレクションビューのコード（`collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)`や`collectionView(_:numberOfItemsInSection:)`、`collectionView(_:didSelectItemAt:)`）を載せてもらえると具体的なアドバイスができます。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。補足します。

Comment: func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return toDoItems?.count ?? 0

        }

        //データを返すメソッド

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{

        let toDo = toDoItems?[indexPath.row]

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! collectionviewcell

        cell.image1.image = toDo?.image

    return cell
        }　　　　Todoリストを元にして作ったのですが。。勉強不足なのでこれを機に学びたいです。

Comment: コメントにコードを書くと非常に読みづらいので質問文を編集するようにしてください。質問文ではコードをキレイに整形して表示することができます。
さて、`toDoItems`という変数はRealmの`Results`型の変数ですか？そうだとしたら、コレクションビューのセルを選択したときに呼ばれるメソッド、`collectionView(_:didSelectItemAt:)`でセルの`indexPath`が取得できるので、ご提示のコードでしているように`let toDo = toDoItems?[indexPath.row]`などとして該当のデータを`toDoItems`から取り出して次の画面に渡します。Segueにはデータを受け渡すAPIはないので、実際には取得した`toDo`を一旦メンバ変数として保存しておいて、`prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)`メソッドで次のビューコントローラのメンバ変数としてデータを渡します。

Comment: 失礼しました、以後気をつけます。また、丁寧に教えていただきありがとうございます。上記のように実装してみたのですが遷移先の画面にデータを無事送れたのか、また受け取ったデータはどのように確認すれば良いのかがわかりません。知識不足でご迷惑おかけします。；；

Comment: 本文に書かれたコードは実際に動かしているコードと同じですか？そうだとすると、UICollectionViewやUICollectionViewDataSource、SegueのAPIの使い方が理解できていません。
`coll‌​ectionView(_:didSele‌​ctItemAt:)`メソッドや、`pr‌​epare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)`は必要に応じてUICollectionViewやシステムから呼び出されるものなので、決まりに従って書く必要があります。
関数の中にネスとしてはいけません。もし私の言ってる意味がよくわからないとすると、おそらくリモートで解決するのは不可能なので簡単な本などで一度基本を勉強されることをお勧めします。

Comment: 返信だいぶ遅くなりましたが、本を読み、岸川さんからの返信を自分なりに理解しながら無事にクリアすることができました。コードをコピペしてばっかではダメだと反省です。。まだまだわからないことだらけで質問すると思うので、その時はまたよろしくお願いいたします。ありがとうございました！